# Что происходит при инициализации поля класса из параметра конструктора с таким же именем?

Tags: java

Например, есть такой класс:

```
public Account {
    int id;

    public Account(int id) {
        id = id;
    }
}
```

Как видите, имя поля класса совпадает с именем параметра конструктора.
Что в данном случае будет означать `id = id`? Присвоится ли значение полю?

Comment: Проще говоря, что объявлено позднее, то скрывает то, что было объявлено до него.:) Поэтому параметр метода скрывает одноименное поле класса, которое, очевидно, предполагается, уже объявлено до объявления параметра.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Нет, параметру `id`, который был передан в конструктор, будет присвоено его же значение.

Убедиться в этом можно, проверив значение `id` после создания объекта:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Account a = new Account(100);
    System.out.println(a.id);
}
```

Будет выведен `0`, а не `100`.

Также это видно, если сделать передаваемый параметр `final`:

```
public Account(final int id)
{
    id = id;
}
```

В этом случае при компиляции возникнет ошибка:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - final parameter id may not be assigned

Для присвоения значения полю класса в данном случае нужно использовать `this.id`:

```
public Account(int id)
{
    this.id = id;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Надо писать

```
this.id = id;
```

чтобы обратиться к переменной класса. Иначе Вы присвоите локальную переменную самой себе.